# Error: Invalid checksum received from debugserver | ionic capacitor run ios -l --external

Tags: ios, angular, ionic4

I'm having intermittent problems with ionic live reload on iOS device
it works in simulator however I receive the above error when trying to run it on iOS device ?  I saw something somewhere that mentioned to build in Xcode first then try again, I did that and sometimes it works, now however its stuck!

appreciate you help!

```
> capacitor run ios --no-sync --target 00008101-X
[capacitor] ✔ Running xcodebuild in 18.20s
[capacitor] ✖ Deploying App.app to 00008101-X - failed!
[capacitor] [error] Error: Invalid checksum received from debugserver
[capacitor]         at GDBProtocolReader.parseBody (/Users/x/Documents/GitHub/xx/node_modules/native-run/dist/ios/lib/protocol/gdb.js:68:23)
[capacitor]         at GDBProtocolReader.onData (/Users/x/Documents/GitHub/xx/node_modules/native-run/dist/ios/lib/protocol/gdb.js:41:36)
[capacitor]         at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
[capacitor]         at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
[capacitor]         at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
[capacitor]         at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
[capacitor]         at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
[capacitor]
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you figured this out, but for a really simple solution, ensure the test device is unlocked and the screen turned on. I was experiencing this when an iPad had gone to sleep.

A deployment from xcode yields a more sensible error message when this is the case, but the capacitor run commands simply display this rather unhelpful message:

`Error: Invalid checksum received from debugserver`